# Getting index of clicked row that's dynamically created

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, html-table, row

I've created a table with three rows that can be expanded with the use of an add button. I want to know the index of every row I click. I have a piece of code that works just fine on the three automatically generated rows, but not on the rows I add using the add button.

Here's a fiddle basically shows my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4wa5kfpz/, my actual code has a lot more stuff in it so this is a basic/stripped version.

As you can see, the rows added between the first two and last do not respond when clicked. I've tried something like (see below, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)) to add the click event to the table rows, but that didn't work.

```
$("table tr").on('click', '#myTable tr', function(e){
    alert('Clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on` event:

```
$("#myTable").on('click', 'tr', function(){
      alert('Clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4wa5kfpz/1/

Comment: Thanks, this worked out excellent! Does this also apply when using an 'each' loop for looping though the dynamically created rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Row indexes</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
    var rows = document.getElementById('my_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = function() {
            alert(this.rowIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="my_table">
<tbody>
    <tr><td>first row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>second row</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

alternatively you could do like this:

```
$('#thetable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

Hope this will help you!!!